# JavaFX - Get color object of rectangle

Tags: java, javafx

My JavaFX application creates rectangles and sets their color with the `setFill` method. Now I want to extract the color of the rectangle, but the `getFill` method returns only a `javafx.scene.paint.Paint` object, not a `javafx.scene.paint.Color` one.

Is there a method to get to the color object?

This is the code snippet:

```
rectangle.setFill(Model.Materials.AIR.getColor());
rectangle.setOnMouseClicked(event -> rectangle.setFill(model.nextMaterialColor(rectangle.getFill())));
```

Comment: If you know you set the fill to a `Color` instance, just downcast it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting the `javafx.scene.paint.Paint` object as a `javafx.scene.paint.Color` object like so:

```
rectangle.setFill(Model.Materials.AIR.getColor());
Color rectangleColor = (Color) rectangle.getFill();
rectangle.setOnMouseClicked(event -> rectangle.setFill(model.nextMaterialColor(rectangleColor)));
```